# Returning the indices in a list

Tags: python, list

```
def test(lst):        
        new_lst = []
        for i in lst:
                if i is True:
                        new_lst.append(lst.index(i))
        return new_lst
```

What the above code is supposed to do:

Loops through each element in the list and if the element is True then append it's indice to a new list. However, it's not doing exactly what it's supposed to do and I can't figure out where I went wrong.

Expected:

```
test([1,2,3,True,True,False])
[3,4]
```

Got:

```
[0,0]
```

Comment: Here's an example to show you what is wrong:
`>>>[1,2,3].index(True)` returns
`0`
activating an index(True) will always return 0 in this case because 1 is also treated as True (not in terms of your ifcheck, but in terms of the check in index(True). The brute force approach would be to iterate in a for loop using range and making the equality with "is", but it would be interesting to see better solutions out there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not what your code returns. Your code returns `[0, 0]` because `list.index` uses equality semantics, not identity semantics, and `True == 1` (try it).

As for a solution, use `enumerate`:

```
new_lst = [index for (index, element) in enumerate(lst) if element is True]
```

More info at http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: Brilliant, i missed the real problem. +1.

Comment: Just to know your opinion, shouldn't `list.index` provide a better way to match? Like reference?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, because a very common use case for `list.index` is to find a string in a list, and long strings are not guaranteed to be interned (compare, for example, `"foo" + "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" == "fooxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` (True) and `"foo" + "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" is "fooxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` (False)). But you still want `index` to work on long strings.

Comment: I wouldn't say no to an optional `key` argument to `index`, though (that'd work in a similar way to `sort`'s `key` argument).

Comment: Then if you wanted to search by identity you'd specify `key = id`, which is nice. That wouldn't help the questioner, though, who has two identical entries in the list and wants to output both distinct indexes. So this answer would still be the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

`list.index` returns the index where the *first* match is found. Another mistake is because, `list.index` uses equality semantics - imagine the `==` symbol - and `True == 1` returns `True`. For more details, see [@max's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21311679/2106009)

Use the built-in function [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead:

```
for i, v in enumerate(lst):
    if v is True:
        new_lst.append(i)
```

Comment: If the last element in the list is `True`, your code will loop infinitely. I would suggest appending to a second list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate` function and do it like this:

```
for index, elem in enumerate(lst):
    if elem is True:
        new_lst.append(index)
```

Your code returns `[0,0]`. This make sense because they are only two `True` values inside the list, but somehow in python `list.index` method when passed a `True` value will return the first `trueish` value, which in your case will be the first element in the lis `1` and thus you're getting `[0,0]` as a result.

Example of `list.index` behavior:

```
>>>l=[1,2,3,True,True,False]
>>>l.index(True)
1    # first trueish value
```

As pointed out by @MaxNoel `list.index` test equality, so like `True == 1`, index 0 is returned when searching for `True`'s index.

Hope this helps!